# Change element text and data-value using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a dropdown menu, and I want to select any of the lis from the parent element of ul when clicked.  Then, take that text and change the "Work Inquiry" (text of #subject) text w/ selected menu item text.

I have comments explaining my predicament on the fiddle.

Here is the jsFiddle :: http://jsfiddle.net/8m4Tj/

```
$("ul#subjects > li").on("click", function () {
  $("#subjects").slideUp(210);
  var liText = $(this).text();
  var newSubjectText = $("#subject").text();
  alert(liText); // this alerts selected item... how do you change #subject.text ???
  alert(newSubjectText); // stays the same
});
```

I don't know if im selecting the wrong item, but I want to replace the data-value and the actual text value.  I'm doing this method since there are no easy ways of styling the `<select>` element.

Comment: $("#subject").text(liText);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the setter version of [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2)

```
$("ul#subjects > li").on("click", function () {
    $("#subjects").slideUp(210);
    $("#subject").text($(this).text());
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kaD2T/)

Answer (score 2):

Use  `.text()` to set the text to span element

Try this

```
$("ul#subjects > li").on("click", function () {
                $("#subjects").slideUp(210);
                var liText = $(this).text();
                $("#subject").text(liText); // this line set the text
                alert(liText);
            });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8m4Tj/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("ul#subjects > li").on("click", function () {
    $("#subjects").slideUp(210);
    var liText = $(this).text();
    $("#subject").text(liText);
    var newSubjectText = $("#subject").text();
    alert(liText);
    alert(newSubjectText); 
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8m4Tj/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this will update data value also

```
$("ul#subjects > li").on("click", function () {
    $("#subjects").slideUp(210);
    $("#subject").text($(this).text()).prop('data-value' $(this).text());
});
```